# Identifying list of regex expressions in Pandas column

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a large pandas dataframe. A column contains text broken down into sentences, one sentence per row. I need to check the sentences for the presence of terms used in various ontologies. Some of the ontologies are fairly large and have more than 100.000 entries. In addition some of the ontologies contain molecule names with hyphens, commas, and other characters that may or may not be present in the text to be examined, hence, the need for regular expressions.

I came up with the code below, but it's not fast enough to deal with my data. Any suggestions are welcome.
Thank you!

```
import pandas as pd                                                             
import re                                                                       


sentences = ["""There is no point in driving yourself mad trying to stop        
             yourself going mad""",                                             
             "The ships hung in the sky in much the same way that bricks don’t"]

sentence_number = list(range(0, len(sentences)))                                
d = {'sentence' : sentences, 'number' : sentence_number}                        

df = pd.DataFrame(d)                                                            

regexes = ['\\bt\\w+', '\\bs\\w+']                                             

big_regex = '|'.join(regexes)                                                   
compiled_regex = re.compile(big_regex, re.I)                                    

df['found_regexes'] = df.sentence.str.findall(compiled_regex)
```

Comment: Not sure how this can be sped up... performance tuning might depend on your actual data.

Comment: Are all  you regexps generic like that or are all of them specific?  The two regexps you showed can be shrunk to a single one - `regex = r'\b[st]\w+'`